# Django: Got 403 when using Oauth2 and SSL

Tags: django, ssl, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-403

I am using Django 1.6 with Oauth2 (django-oauth-toolkit) and the site is SSL secure via apache.

- When i get a token and using it **without** SSL - I reach the api and get 200.
- If the token is not valid, i get 403, as expected. OK.
- when i use the SSL **without** the Oauth2 - it's also pass OK.

But when i use them together SSL and Oauth I get 403.

Can someone give me a clue what am i missing?

Thanks in advances

Hagay.

Comment: Are you getting the error when trying to invoke your oauth callback function? Are you using manage.py runserver to run the server?

Comment: Do i need to add and extra data when using ssl ?

Comment: Not sure about your set-up, but a few things can go wrong. You need a public address for the oauth callback url, you cannot run it locally. The public host must be added to the allowed hosts in Django setttings. If you are using manage.py runserver, please note that it's not ssl ready. You need to install a package like django-sslserver to be able to support ssl in this mode.

Comment: I don't have any problem getting the token (using authorization code grant type).

Comment: @Mark, it ocure behind apache(because this is how i enable the SSL). If i use it like manage.py (w/o ssl) i don;t ahve any problem. Can i use SSL directly from the django app server without using apache - i need it for prodction..

Comment: Maybe there is an handshake between the oauth2 and the SSL ?

Comment: the ALLOWED_HOST is empty and it work without SSL so I guess the solution is not the ALLOWED_HOST, :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting strange issues with HTTP authorization under Apache/WSGI/Django, but not when running `manage.py runserver`, you might need this command in your Apache site config:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization on
```

If the setting is not switched on, then WSGI "swallows" all authorization headers and doesn't pass them on to your Python code, apparently for security reasons.

See [the WSGI module docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html) for more information.